# Wrong Input Layout for DX11

Tags: layout, input, direct3d11

I tried to write new vertex shader (exactly vertex shader is NULL and input is going to geometry shader but this shouldn't be a difference) with different input layout like other shaders in my application. But I'm getting invalid arg during input layout creation and don't know why. So here is my C++/shader code:

Vertex definition in C++:

```html
typedef struct vertex
{
 vertex() {}
 vertex( const XMFLOAT3& p,
      const XMFLOAT4& c,
   const XMFLOAT3& n,
   const XMFLOAT3& tu,
   const XMFLOAT2& t)
  : Position(p), Normal(n), TangentU(tu), TexC(t) {}

 vertex( float px, float py, float pz,
   float n1, float n2, float n3,
   float tu1, float tu2, float tu3,   
   float t1, float t2)
  : Position(px,py,pz), Normal(n1, n2, n3), TangentU(tu1, tu2, tu3), TexC(t1, t2) {}

 vertex (float px, float py, float pz)
  : Position(px,py,pz), Normal(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), TangentU(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), TexC(0.0f, 0.0f) {}

 bool operator==(const vertex& v)
 {
  return (memcmp(&(this->Position),&(v.Position),sizeof(Position)) == 0);
 }

 vertex& operator=(const vertex& v)
 {
  memcpy(this, &v, sizeof(*this));
  return *this;
 }

 bool operator!=(const vertex& v)
 {
  if ((Position.x != v.Position.x) ||
   (Position.y != v.Position.y) ||
            (Position.z != v.Position.z))
     return true;

  return false;
 }

 void Init(void)
 {
  ZeroMemory(this,sizeof(*this));
 }

 XMFLOAT3 Position;

 //data for lighting
 XMFLOAT3 Normal;

 XMFLOAT3 TangentU;

 //data for texturing
 XMFLOAT2 TexC;
} TVertex;
```

VertexIn definition in HLSL:

```html
struct GMVectorVertexIn_Basic
{
 float3 PosL  : POSITION;
 float3 NormalL : NORMAL;
 float3 TangentL : TANGENT;
};
```

Input layout description:

```html
const BYTE GM_VECTORS_ATTRIBUTE_COUNT = 3;
const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC InputLayoutDesc::GMVectorBasicDesc[GM_VECTORS_ATTRIBUTE_COUNT] =
{
 { "Position", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
 { "NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
 { "TANGENT", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 24, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
};
```

And input layout creation:

```html
Effects::BasicFX->GMVectorBasicTech->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);
HR(device->CreateInputLayout(InputLayoutDesc::GMVectorBasicDesc, GM_VECTORS_ATTRIBUTE_COUNT, passDesc.pIAInputSignature, passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &GMVectorBasicLayout));
```

FX File:

```html
struct GMVectorVertexIn_Basic
{
 float3 PosL  : POSITION;
 float3 NormalL : NORMAL;
 float3 TangentL : TANGENT;
};

struct GMVectorVertexOUT_Basic
{
 float4 PosH    : SV_POSITION;
 float3 PosW    : POSITION;
 float4 Color   : COLOR;
};

[maxvertexcount(4)]
void GS_GMVectorBasic(point GMVectorVertexIn_Basic gin[1], inout LineStream<GMVectorVertexOUT_Basic> lineStream)
{
 GMVectorVertexOUT_Basic p1_out, p2_out;
 float3 pointPosition;

 p1_out.PosH = mul(float4(gin[0].PosL, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);
 p1_out.PosW = mul(float4(gin[0].PosL, 1.0f), gWorld).xyz;

 if (gDrawNormalVectors)
 {
  p1_out.Color = gNormalVectorColor;

  pointPosition = gin[0].PosL + gin[0].NormalL;
  p2_out.PosH = mul(float4(pointPosition, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);
  p2_out.PosW = mul(float4(pointPosition, 1.0f), gWorld).xyz;
  p2_out.Color = gNormalVectorColor;

  lineStream.Append(p1_out);
  lineStream.Append(p2_out);
 }

 if (gDrawTangentVectors)
 {
  p1_out.Color = gTangentVectorColor;

  pointPosition = gin[0].PosL + gin[0].TangentL;
  p2_out.PosH = mul(float4(pointPosition, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);
  p2_out.PosW = mul(float4(pointPosition, 1.0f), gWorld).xyz;
  p2_out.Color = gTangentVectorColor;

  lineStream.Append(p1_out);
  lineStream.Append(p2_out);
 }
}

float4 PS_GMVectorBasic(GMVectorVertexOUT_Basic pin, uniform bool gUseFog) : SV_Target
{
 float4 retColor = pin.Color;

 //fogging
 if (gUseFog)
 {
  float distToEye = length(gEyePosW - pin.PosW);
  float fogLerp = saturate((distToEye - gFogStart)/gFogEnd);

  //Blend the fog color and lit color
  retColor = lerp(retColor, gFogColor, fogLerp);
 }

 return retColor;
}
```

And Technique definition:

```html
technique11 GMVectorBasicTech
{
 pass P0
 {
  SetVertexShader(NULL);
  SetGeometryShader(CompileShader(gs_5_0, GS_GMVectorBasic()));
  SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_5_0, PS_GMVectorBasic(false)));
 }
}
```

I checked arguments count, leyout description and CreateInputLayout calling and I can't see where is a problem. Most probably I'm too tired to see a trivial bug...

Error displayed in dialog:

```
Unexpected error encountered. 
Error code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)

D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout: Encoded Signature size doesn't match specified size. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #161: CREATEINPUTLAYOUT_UNPARSEABLEINPUTSIGNATURE]

First-chance exception at 0x76BCC42D in EngineDX.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x002BF488.

First-chance exception at 0x76BCC42D in EngineDX.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x002BF484.

Basic Classes\InputLayout\InputLayout.cpp(76): device->CreateInputLayout(InputLayoutDesc::GMVectorBasicDesc, GM_VECTORS_ATTRIBUTE_COUNT, passDesc.pIAInputSignature, passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &GMVectorBasicLayout) hr=E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
```

Thanks for help.

EDIT 3.11.2014: I solved the problem by creating vertex shader, which only resend vertex data to geometry shader. Whith this, input layout was successfully created without other changes.

Comment: The first logical step is to enable DirectX 11 [debug layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Debug). After that you either resolve problem quickly yourself or post full error description here.

Comment: Well I add debug output to my post. It says: Encoded Signature size doesn't match specified size. But I still can't see an error.

Comment: I add whole FX file and technique definition into my post.

Comment: You can have a NULL Geometry Shader, but I don't believe you can have a NULL Vertex Shader.

Comment: BTW, are you using the latest [Effects 11](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568)?

Comment: "BTW, are you using the latest Effects 11?"

I'm using Effects 11 which were included in DVD from Frank Luna Book to learn DX11. There was source code to them which I only recompiled with Visual Studio 2013 compiler. I bought a book 2,5 year ago. I upgrade it  when I finished what I'm up to. THanks for hint.

That's possibly true. When I do changes written in EDIT part of my main comment, everything is working as expected.